# Quantifiers and Truth Values

Tags: quantifiers

Determine the truth value of each statement, assuming that x and y are real numbers, and justify your answer.

1. $\forall$x, $\exists$y such that xy=1
2. $\exists$y such that $\forall$x , xy=1

I understand the first problem to be true. Since the equation can be "solved" in terms of y, I found that y was a reciprocal of x. So now xy=1 is true.
The second problem confuses me. The books says its truth value is false. The only reasoning I have for that answer is the question is the reverse of the first. Can anyone help me understand why the second question is false?

Comment: The first statement is false if $x=0$.

Comment: The first one is "given a real, pick it's inverse" the second one is "pick an inverse for *all* reals" which is impossible. The ordering of the quantifiers is the difficulty here.

Comment: Ok! Now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: The second is problematic, when x = 0, also.  There is no y, such that, when x = 0, $xy= 1$.

Comment: Even if we exclude $0$ from the domain of x, y,  There is no specific y, such that $\forall x$, $xy = 1$.